# Saving a registered user to my database model with form submission

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am using django-registration and i can't figure out how to save the user to my database model after the user hits submit. the information in the form needs to have the user with it.

how do I access the user model, is it with requestcontext? in my views.py file?

Comment: When do you want to save user? It will be saved by `django-registration` after user fill the registration form. In most cases you shouldn't do this manually.

Comment: A logged in user fills out a form, the form is saved to the database,the database needs to know the user that saved the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the user has already registered, and logged in? request.user should contain the current user, if I'm remembering correctly.